# Unable to use an utility class

Tags: java, android, class, utility

I have a problem trying to use the method **calcularRuta** from outside an activity. The method returns a value depending on the inputs it has. I can't get any results because i tried debugging it and it doesn't even enter the method, so it when i have to use the variable **ruta** in the next line it's null.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            try {
                String qr = DecodeQR.zxing(mRgba);

                int origen = Integer.valueOf(qr);
                int destino = Integer.valueOf(bundle.getString("DESTINO"));
                boolean ascensor = bundle.getBoolean("ASCENSOR");

                if (ruta == null)
                    ruta = IniciarBusqueda.calcularRuta(origen, destino, ascensor);

                updateScreen(qr, ruta.toString());

            } catch (ChecksumException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the problem but i can't... Any thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT: Changed the utility method to static.

Comment: Why don't you make that method as `public static`? And call it like `ClassName.MehodName`.

Comment: "doesn't even enter the method" ? are you sure "IniciarBusqueda.getInstance()" is not returning null ?

Comment: I tried to use it as static but it doesn't work. Also the utility class is working fine because i've used it in other works...

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't instantiate an activity.

2) Make that method `public static` so that you can access it by using `Classname.methodName`. No need to instantiate the class.

Comment: I tried to do that but the problem persists... In doesn't enter the method.